# How to syntax highlight the searching result of cscope in vim?

Tags: vim, cscope

As title.
When I use the command "cs find s " (which the symbol could be a function or variable names), the searching result is showed below the vim.

However, the result is not syntax highlight and it's difficult for me to find the files I want.

Are ther any way to let the result syntax-ize?

I try the method that export some environment variables to "vim", such as $EIDTOR and $CSCOPE_EDITOR. But all of them did't work.

I try to figure out what is the type of the window shows the result and set the syntax on it. But when the result shows up, and I executed the command ":set filetype?" and ":set buftype?" and both the results show the same as C code. ("c" or filetype and "" for buftype).

I don't know how to achieve what I want.

Please help me to do that, thanks!

Comment: I don't have cscope installed, so having a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: Have you read `:help cscope`? There's a lot there and you will find that cscope results are shown in a *quickfix list*. So that's your special window. I don't think there's a way to have syntax highlighting. I think (but I might be mistaken) only the matching line is known at that point and syntax recognition is hard if not impossible without context.

Comment: Cscope results *can* be shown in a quickfix window. When they are not, they are displayed in a pre-formatted way in the command-line, where syntax highlighting is currently impossible beyond `:help :echohl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think there is a workaround for it.

First, let the result shows in a quickfix.

`:set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-,a-`

Then, enable the C syntax on quickfix window:

`autocmd FileType qf setlocal filetype=c`

[image]

The syntax is shown in quickfix.